# Like counter - handleLike function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am  trying to add a like counter per challenge. Every time I click on the like icon, the handleLike() starts working and should add 1 like to that specific challenge. I tried to do this in my handleLike() function but struggle to make it work. I guess my approach is not changing the like in the specific challenge.

---

```
class Allchallenges extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()

        this.state = {
           challenges: []
        }

        this.handleLike=this.handleLike.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        axios({
            method: "GET",
            url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE}/allchallenges`,
            withCredentials: true
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            let challengeslist = response.data;
            this.setState({challenges: challengeslist})
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("You've made an error charles: ",error)
        })
    }

    handleLike(challengeId){
    console.log("This is the handlelikebutton speaking!")
    const likedchallenge = this.state.challenges.filter(challenge => challenge._id === challengeId)       
    likedchallenge.likes++
}

    render(){
        return (
            <DefaultLayout>
                <div className="challengeoverviewlist">
                    <h1>All challenges</h1>   

                    <div className="challengeboxes">
                        {    
                        this.state.challenges.map(challenge => 
                            (
                                <div className="totalbox" key={challenge._id}>

                                    <div className="likedislikesbox">
                                        <div className="likecontainer">
                                            <div className="leftalignment"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faThumbsUp} onClick={()=>this.handleLike(challenge._id)}/></div>
                                                <p className="likestat">{challenge.likes}</p>
                                        </div>

                                        <div className="dislikecontainer">
                                            <div className="leftalignment"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faThumbsDown}/></div>
                                            <p className="dislikestat">{challenge.dislikes}</p>
                                        </div>

                                        <div className="satisfactioncontainer">
                                            <div className="leftalignment"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBalanceScale}/></div>
                                            <p className="satisfactionstat">{challenge.likes/(challenge.dislikes + challenge.likes)*100}%</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <Challengebox 
                                        key={challenge._id} 
                                        id={challenge._id} 
                                        title={challenge.title} 
                                        description={challenge.description}
                                    />

                                    <button className="deletebutton" onClick={()=> this.onDelete(challenge._id)}>
                                        Delete
                                    </button>

                                </div>
                            ))                                                                      
                        }
                    </div>

                </div>    
            </DefaultLayout>
        )
    }
}

export default Allchallenges
```

---

```
const challengeSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    description: String,
    initiator: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:"User"},
    likes: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    dislikes: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    satisfaction: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    likealready: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    dislikealready: { type: Boolean, default: false }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to specific error messages since none were provided, but one observation:

You have:

```
    handleLike(challengeId){
    console.log("This is the handlelikebutton speaking!")
    const likedchallenge = this.state.challenges.filter(challenge => challenge._id === challengeId)       
    likedchallenge.likes++
}
```

If you look at what [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) does, it returns a copy of an array that matches your condition.

So in this case, you have potentially filtered the array to one item (with the matching challenge ID), but you are manipulating it as if it is the challenge object, not an array of up to one challenge.

You'd end up with something like

```
    const likedchallenge = [Challenge];
    // Try to increment likes
    likedchallenge.likes++;
    // This tries to increment lies on the ARRAY containing the challenge object
```

You probably want to GET the challenge object, e.g. using [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead.

---

**UPDATE: Regarding React's setState**

As noted in the comments below, manipulating state directly is not something you want to do. Instead, you should rely on informing React of your state change. Roughly, it might look something like:

```
    handleLike(challengeId) {
      this.setState(state => {
        challenges: state.challenges.map(c => {
          if (c._id === challengeId) {
            c.likes++;
          }
          return c;
        }),
      });
    }
```

Comment: See and familiarize yourself with the linked documentation for `.find()`. you'd want to use that in place of `.filter()` where you are extracting `likedchallenge`.

Comment: I tried doing that and have this now:     handleLike(challengeId){
        console.log("This is the handlelikebutton speaking!")
        const likedchallenge = this.state.challenges.find(challenge => challenge._id === challengeId) 
        console.log(likedchallenge)      
        likedchallenge.likes++
    }   Just wondering how I can get that back in the challengesarray and replace it with the old one?

Comment: It never has left the array, You simply have a reference to it and it is change/incremented in-place. You can verify this by logging the state of the array after the change.

Comment: ok understood! Just wondering then why my {challenge.likes} in the render is then not being updated with every click? <p className="likestat">{challenge.likes}</p>

Comment: See https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly. I suspect you should be using setState instead of direct manipulation. This is an independent issue from the first one.

Comment: would you mind giving it a try? how can I update the state here so that my like counter goes 1 up?

Comment: What should I add in between  this.setState({})

Comment: anyone else maybe?

Comment: oh wow I accidentally found it, you need an empty this.setState({}). Anyone know why this works? Is it resetting the state?

Comment: See the updated answer for additional details. You shouldn't use an empty object but instead make the update using setState and not directly, that may work in this instance to use the empty object, but it's not following the correct guidance on how to manage state.